# Adding divider to MUI MenuItem adds extra border

Tags: css, material-ui, menuitem

I needed to use a `divider` to the `MUI` `MenuItem` and it adds an extra border to the item where the divider has been added. THe highlighted item on the image is the item where I set the `divider= true` and the border is visible. How can this be handled so that it doesn't add the border?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your code? It wasn't very clear from the image where the problem can be. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe issue was that when the menu item divider has been set to true, it was adding some margin to the the `<li>` item. So setting it to zero only when the divider is on fixed the issue.

It is fixed by adding the following check on the `<MenuItem>`:

```
 <MenuItem 
    ...
    divider={divider}
    sx={{ ...(divider && { margin: 0 }) }} 
 >
```